# Docker : Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-machine

I pushed a docker image from an older dev machine, and now I can't push or pull to that repo.

The server errors with

```
Invalid parent ID.
```

And my dev box errors with

```
Error pulling image (latest) from docker.io/repo/appname,
Driver aufs failed to create image rootfs {ID}: 
open /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs/layers/{ID}: no such file or directory
```

I'm running OSX 10.11.4  with docker-machine 0.5.4 on both setups.

I've tried removing dangling images, stopped images, and I destroyed and rebuilt the docker-machine env.

Any idea whats happened?

m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what the issue was in the end, but removing all images, then rebuilding and re pushing fixed it.

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi $(docker images -a -q)

docker build -t repo/app .
docker push repo/app
```

And after that I could pull it again on the server and other machines.